# How do Hindus wash genitals and anus during bath?

Tags: dharma, dharma-shastras, bath, showering, snana

According to the shastras, [one should wear a cloth while bathing/showering.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12169/is-bathing-without-cloth-a-sin)

This is one reason why Krishna stole the gopis' clothes.

But if you're wearing underwear while showering, how are you supposed to wash the genitals and anus? Are you supposed to pull down the underwear and wash the genitals and anus? But doesn't doing so go against the reason for wearing underwear, which is that not wearing is offensive to Varuna?

Or do Hindus simply not wash them and have stinky and dirty genitals and anus?

Comment: The goal of Hinduism is to get liberation away from Maya, how you wash, or even do not wash is not of any concern here. How are genitals and anus washed may be properly indicated by a medical professional.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha It is of concern, did you see the shastra verses? It could be aparadha to Varuna deva. And anyway this doesn't answer the question, I want to know how to wash crotch and anus

Comment: Purification of genitals etc. happen before bath not during bath. After excreting the organs should be purified according to the rules of Saucha given in scriptures. This purification process happens before taking bath -- 5.136. He who desires to be pure, must clean the organ by one (application of) earth, the anus by (applying
earth) three (times), the (left) hand alone by (applying it) ten (times), and both (hands) by (applying it) seven
(times) @Ikshvaku

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this , @Rickross

Comment: I don't find any problem with this question, some people unnecessarily downvoted it.

Comment: @Rickross Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> **one should wear a cloth while bathing/showering.**

The reason for the wearing cloth is because man is expected to bath in a public place :

***manu 4. 203.** Let him always **bathe in rivers, in ponds, dug by the gods (themselves), in lakes, and in waterholes or springs**.*

> **But if you're wearing underwear while showering, how are you supposed to wash the genitals and anus?**

washing organs is also mandatory though there may be practical challenges as even toilet is outside the house :

***manu 4.151.** **Far from his dwelling** let him remove urine (and ordure), far (let him remove) the water used for washing his feet, and far the remnants of food and the water from his bath.*

***manu 5.136.** He who desires to be pure, **must clean the organ** by one (application of) earth, the anus by (applying earth) three (times), the (left) hand alone by (applying it) ten (times), and both (hands) by (applying it) seven (times).*